# ADF Web application database connection issue on application STOP/START on Weblogic console

Tags: database, weblogic, oracle-adf

I have two ADF Web applications (app1 and app2). Both of them are using the Business Service technology. I am using Jdev 12.2.1.3.0. I deploy app1 to Weblogic server (or Integrated Weblogic Server) and it runs well. When I do STOP and the START on app1 on the server console and then run app1 again, I get null value from (ViewObjectImpl)findViewObject(“xx”) call, which looks like losing database connection. However, if I do “UPDATE” on app1 (kind of redeploying application), it is running again. App2 does not have this issue. Both applications are using the same ba4j.xcfg. Here is ba4j.xcfg file

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<!---->
<BC4JConfig version="11.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bc4j/configuration">
<AppModuleConfigBag ApplicationName="model.service.AppModule" default="AppModuleLocal">
  <AppModuleConfig jbo.project="model.Model" ApplicationName="model.service.AppModule" DeployPlatform="LOCAL" name="AppModuleLocal">
     <AM-Pooling jbo.ampool.maxinactiveage="60000" jbo.ampool.timetolive="120000" jbo.ampool.monitorsleepinterval="30000"
                 jbo.dofailover="true"/>
     <Database jbo.TypeMapEntries="Java" jbo.locking.mode="optimistic"/>
     <Security AppModuleJndiName="model.service.AppModule"/>
     <Custom ns0:JDBCDataSource="jdbc/xxDS" ns0:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bc4j/configuration" xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bc4j/configuration"/>
  </AppModuleConfig>
  <AppModuleConfig jbo.project="model.Model" ApplicationName="model.service.AppModule" DeployPlatform="LOCAL" name="AppModuleShared">
     <AM-Pooling jbo.ampool.dynamicjdbccredentials="false" jbo.ampool.resetnontransactionalstate="false" jbo.ampool.maxpoolsize="1" jbo.ampool.isuseexclusive="false"/>
     <Database jbo.TypeMapEntries="Java" jbo.locking.mode="optimistic"/>
     <Security AppModuleJndiName="model.service.AppModule"/>
     <Custom ns0:JDBCDataSource="jdbc/xxDS" ns0:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bc4j/configuration" xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bc4j/configuration"/>
  </AppModuleConfig>
```

Could anyone help me to identify the issue and tell me where I should look into it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is your datasource deploy on the same weblogic server as your app and up as well ?

Comment: Yes, we used JNDI on weblogic server. The app is up running after deployment. However, after Stop and Start app on weblogic console, app stops running. If we do UPDATE on app, it runs again.  Thanks.